# A POST API django-rest-framework. After storing to model, call postgres function and send an email

Tags: python, django, function, class, django-rest-framework

My API call works and stores the data to a table.
After this is done, I want it to run a stored procedure/function in `postgres`.
After this I want a sendgrid email to be sent.

My thoughts are that I'm screwing it up in the **views.py** class.

Code is as follows:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'^$',
        views.ProcList.as_view(),
        name='proc-list'
    ),
    ...
]
```

**views.py**

```
class ProcList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Proc.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProcSerializer
    #permission_classes = (IsAdminOrReadOnly,)
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'proc_id'

    q = Proc.store() 
    if isNum(q[0][0]):
        trans_id = int(q[0][0])
        trans = Transaction.objects.get(trans_id=trans_id)
        proc_id = trans.proc_id
        proc = Proc.objects.get(proc_id=proc_id)
        first_name = proc.first_name
        pdf_name = str(proc.proc_u_id)
        email = proc.email

        if Event.objects.filter(channel='EMAIL', trans_id=trans_id).exists():
            sendemail2(first_name, pdf_name, email)
```

`Proc.Store()` is a model containing the `postgres` function. 
`sendemail2(first_name, pdf_name, email)` is the function that sends the sendgrid email

My issue is that `Proc.Store()` works if run separately or in the `python` console.
The `sendemail2(first_name, pdf_name, email)` also works separately if run in e.g. the `python` console.
But somehow my class is wrongly build so it does not execute the `Proc.Store` and `sendemail(...)`.

A weird effect is that when I save something and the server restarts (or similar) it runs the two functions, but not after I have called the `API`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your special code in a method of the class. The docs on [`ListCreateAPIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview) specify the `post()` method for creation of instances.

So you could try this:

```
class ProcList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    # same attributes
    ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        resp = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

        # here goes your custom code
        q = Proc.store() 
        if isNum(q[0][0]):
            ...

        return resp
```